# how to import a json file using vite dynamicly

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n, vite

I am using [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) in a [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org) project, and I want to import my locale files with vite dynamicly.

when I am using webpack, those code run well

**plugins/i18n.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import config from '@/config';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

let messages = Object;

config.locale.available.forEach(locale => {
    messages[locale] = require(`~/locales/${locale}.json`);
});

export default ({ app, store }) => {
    app.i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: store.state.locale.locale,
        messages: messages
    });
}
```

---

I got that there is no `require()` in vitejs, also the [glob-import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) feature of vitejs

1. So I tried like this below first:

```js
let messages = Object,
    languages = import.meta.glob('../locales/*.json'); // => languages = {} (languages only get {} value)

config.locale.available.forEach(locale => {
    messages[locale] = languages[`../locales/${locale}.json`];
});
```

But the `languages` only got `{}` value.

2. Then I tried to use `import()`

```js
let messages = Object,
    translate = lang => () => import(`@/locales/${lang}.json`).then(i => i.default || i);

config.locale.available.forEach(locale => {
    messages[locale] = translate(locale);
});
```

no errors in both terminal and console, but no locale file has been loaded correctly.

---

only if I `import()` one by one, the issue will disappear:

```js
import en from '@/locales/en.json';
import fr from '@/locales/fr.json';
import ja from '@/locales/ja.json';

let messages = Object;

messages['en'] = en;
messages['fr'] = fr;
messages['ja'] = ja;
```

---

#### [**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gould-pp9xh)

But, how to import it dynamicly?

I googled it, but helped little. Greate thank for anyone help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I think I figured out something based on [@LiuQixuan's answer on GitHub](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/77).

```js
//Importing your data 
const data = import.meta.glob('../locales/*.json')

//Ref helps with promises I think. I'm sure there are more elegant ways.
const imp = ref([{}])

// From https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/77
// by LiuQixuan commented on Jun 20

for (const path in data) {
    data[path]().then((mod) => { 
        imp.value.push(mod)
    })
}
```

From there, I iterated through the `imp.values`, then I can call each file in a loop, grabbing the data with:

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(**Your data**))
```

My example Vue HTML was this:

```html
    <div v-for="(module,i) in imp" :key="i">
          <div v-for="(data,j) in module" :key="j">

            //at this point you can read it fully with {{ data }}

            <div v-for="(jsonText, k) in JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))" :key=k">
              {{ jsonText.text }}
              <div v-for="insideJson in jsonText" :key="insideJson">
                {{ insideJson.yourtext }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

With that, I could access every object in the file. You have other needs I think, but this proves that you can access each file without independent imports.

I know this is a little rough. I used the Stringify parse because the data was always returning as never, so I couldn't directly access. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but this is what I figured out.

I was originally trying to import images dynamically, after figuring it out, I then applied the method to your issue.

For anyone wondering on dynamic multi-image import from folder, use:

```js
new URL(*, import.meta.url)
```

As in, like before, but with the addition:

```js
    for (const path in modules) {
      modules[path]().then(() => {
        //*************
        const imgURL = new URL(path, import.meta.url)
        //*************
        gallery.value.push(imgURL)
      })
    }
    //Then reference that gallery.value in your :src
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [@Lucas Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17010481/lucas-dawson)'s answer

for those who have to run their code on both vite and webpack

**plugins/i18n.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

/***
make sure your public config has `VITE_` prefix or it can't be seen in the client side
https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files
***/
let messages = Object,
    locales = process.env.VITE_AVAILABLE_LOCALES.split(',');

// check is using vite or webpack
if (typeof __webpack_require__ !== 'function') {
    // for vite

    /***
    glob and globEager are both work for this
    https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

    the differences is
    `glob` will return a dynamic import function (lazy load)
    `globEager` will return the data of the file from the path directly

    if you use `glob`, don't forget `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(**Your data**))`
    if you have trouble with this, use `globEager` may save your day
    ***/

    let modules = import.meta.globEager('/lang/*.json');
    locales.forEach(locale => {
        messages[locale] = modules[`/lang/${locale}.json`];
    });
}
else {
    // for webpack (storybook)
    locales.forEach(locale => {
        messages[locale] = require(`~/lang/${locale}.json`);
    });
}

export default ({ app, store }) => {
    app.i18n = new VueI18n({
        locale: store.getters['locale/locale'],
        messages
    });
}
```

Thanks again for [@Lucas Dawson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17010481/lucas-dawson)'s answer!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works for some cases, but in my case, I needed to have access to a localized text from the start without a delay from Promises generated by `import.meta.glob`.

What helped me was this, as it is instant when the files are already available:

```js
const requireLocale = async fileName => {
  try {
    const files = import.meta.globEager("./i18n/*.json")
    const texts = files[`./i18n/${fileName}.json`]
    return texts?.default || {}
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.warn(`The file "./i18n/${fileName}.json" could not be loaded.`)
    return {}
  }
}
```