# vite error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" when reading JSON files with dynamic file-names

Tags: javascript, vite

How can I refactor this function, so that it works with `vite`:

```
export function readFileFromDisk(file, folder) {
  // console.log(`Reading file ${file} from ${folder}`);
  let book = "";
  if (typeof folder !== "undefined") {
    book = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require(`../data/${folder}/${file}`)));
  } else {
    book = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require(`../data/${file}`)));
  }
  return book;
}
```

Currently vite reports `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I cannot use `import` as it must precede all other statements, which is not possible with this current function syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to import a json file using vite dynamicly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67822238/how-to-import-a-json-file-using-vite-dynamicly)

Comment: Thank You @AlexanderNenashev, but I have decided to stay with vue-cli. Don't want to change code for a build tool - at least not know